# Bulk inserting to MYSQL through NodeJS With Multiple Placeholders and SELECT

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, bulkinsert

I'm having trouble getting the following to work. Any help would be massively appreciated

```
var values = [
        ['Product1', 1, 1],
        ['Product2', 1, 1],
    ];

    dbConn.query(
        'INSERT INTO tblQuoteItems (ProductIDFK,QuoteIDFK,CustomerIDFK) VALUES ((SELECT ProductIDPK FROM tblProducts WHERE ProductName=?),?,?)',
        [values],
        function (err, res) {
            if (err) {
                
                result(null, err);
            } else {
                
                result(null, res);
            }
        }
    );
```

the error response shows that it is dumping all of the array into the first placeholder rather than one value per placeholder and iterating over the number of array elements. Here is the SQL created from the above :

```
INSERT INTO tblQuoteItems (ProductIDFK,QuoteIDFK,CustomerIDFK) VALUES ((SELECT ProductIDPK FROM tblProducts WHERE ProductName=('Product1', 1, 1), ('Product2', 1, 1)),?,?)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that may be in the samew situation. The answer I found was to create and use a temporary table then SELECT from that to find the foreign key IDs. I was unable to find a way to use placeholders in the Nodejs MySQL library to map individually to each element in an array.